# How to fetch values using STUFF Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, stuff

I am using the below code which is giving me no. of Orders each month

but I want to stuff order no.s in each month column.

| Ord Ref | Month | Party Name | Name of Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Order 1 | Jun | Vendor 1 | Item A |
| Order 2 | Jun | Vendor 1 | Item B |
| Order 3 | Jun | Vendor 2 | Item B |
| Order 4 | Jun | Vendor 3 | Item C |
| Order 5 | Jul | Vendor 4 | Item C |

Output I need

| Name of Item | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item A |  |  |  |  |  | Order1 |  |
| Item B |  |  |  |  |  | Order2, Order 3 |  |
| Item C |  |  |  |  |  | Order 4 | Order5 |

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [Name Of Item], 
       DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate) [Month],
       Count(1)[Ord Ref]
      FROM Stock_Master_Pur_Ord_Del
      GROUP BY [Name Of Item], 
      DATENAME(MONTH, OrderDate)) AS MontlySalesData
PIVOT(sum([Ord Ref])
    FOR Month IN ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],
    [June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],
    [December]) )AS MNamePivot
```

Comment: Please provide an example output dataset and explain the issue with your current query

Comment: Looking at your query `Ord Ref` is an integer, but in the sample data that you shown, it is a `string` ?

Comment: it is a varchar

Comment: Example what I need is 

Item A has two orders in June so I need Test , Order1,Order2  under june column for example

Comment: currently, it is giving me count or sum of total no. of orders I raised in Jun

Comment: Since your columns are fixed, you could write 12 `string_agg` to do what you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of SQL Server (I mean for four years now) support `string_agg()`.  You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name_of_item,
       string_agg(case when month = 'Jan' then ord_ref end) within group (order by ord_ref) as jan,
       string_agg(case when month = 'Feb' then ord_ref end) within group (order by ord_ref) as feb,
       string_agg(case when month = 'Mar' then ord_ref end) within group (order by ord_ref) as mar,
       string_agg(case when month = 'Apr' then ord_ref end) within group (order by ord_ref) as apr,
       string_agg(case when month = 'May' then ord_ref end) within group (order by ord_ref) as may,
       string_agg(case when month = 'Jun' then ord_ref end) within group (order by ord_ref) as jun,
       string_agg(case when month = 'Jul' then ord_ref end) within group (order by ord_ref) as jul
from Stock_Master_Pur_Ord_Del
group by name_of_item;
```